# Best practice for loading images on nativescript angular iOS

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm building out an iPhone and Android app using nativescript angular.

Since the app will be loading images in a list view, I have the nativescript fresco plugin to take care of loading the images and it works beautifully btw. Unfortunately this only take care of Android side.

I was wondering what other developers use when developing for nativescript apps for IOS.

**clarification**: what I'm really trying to figure out is what should I use to replace fresco when developing for ios.

Also, I now have all these Fresco tags for all the images for android. But what do you do when you are ready to develop for IOS? Do I need to have *ngIF statements on all of them for android and use default Image tags for IOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `<android></android>` or `<ios></ios>` tags for platform specific views

e.g

```
<android>
<FrescoDrawee [imageUri]="someImage"></FrescoDrawee>
</android>
```

```
<ios>
<Image [src]="someImage"></Image>
</ios>
```

Comment: Thank you for this info. I should edit my question as my main question is really what is the alternative others are using to replace fresco when developing for ios.

Comment: iOS manages memory better than android, why Facebook only made fresco for android, they didn't need it for iOS.

Comment: @ZeroNine Brad is right also the 2.4 which is coming next month you will not need to use fresco because the {N} team did some updates to the image module (I tested it) and it works great!!!

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the info! Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is also the `SDWebImage` library which can automatically manage caching.

http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SDWebImage/4.1.2/